# opencvsharp application post-setup not working

Tags: c#, winforms, opencv

I have made an application in openCVSharp.It works great. I have made the setup/installer to this app and have included all the dlls required, also as mentioned in the Readme file that comes along openCVSharp, i have included openCVSharExtern.dll . When i execute the setup in my PC, its installs the app fine and the app runs fine too. But when i install the app on someother pc, it installs fine, but when its run on that pc, it throws an exception P/Invoke and something about cxcore210.dll...

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reference the DLL in your project, are you referencing the DLL in the location that gets installed by the installer?

e.g. if the DLL is installed one directory back in a certain folder then it should be referenced on your PC when you build it, one directory back with the same named folder.

I'm just wondering if when you build the app on you PC you are referencing the DLL from a different location (which works find on your PC because it exists) but on another PC it can't find it.